# Sharing Image using intent in watsApp is not working

Tags: android

I am sharing two URI image resource which from mipmap and ACTION_GET_CONTENT used URI.

```
public void shareUsingIntent() {
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    i.setType("image/*");
    i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, getUri());
    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(i, "Share Image"));
}
public Uri getUri() {
    if (selectedImageUri != null) {
        return selectedImageUri;
    } else {
        return Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
    }
}
```

It was worked in ACTION_GET_CONTENT used URI but mipmap resource was not working in some application like Facebook and watsapp. I read from some stack answer that Image must be add in Extenrnal storage. Its not working for this URI.

```
Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/" + R.mipmap.ic_launcher
```

in what's app and Facebook and why it was working in other app like default messing app, Twitter etc.?

Comment: only in whats app or other all in?

Comment: whats app and facebook both which I was checked.

Comment: check it below anser

Answer (score 1):

Try this function:
// if targetSDK >= 23, **please check for runtime permission:**     `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />`

Also add the same permission to your Manifest file.

```
   private void shareViaWhatsApp() {

        Uri imageUri = null;
        try {
            imageUri = Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(this.getContentResolver(),
                    BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher), null, null)); //You may need to check for permission for this. 
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {

        }

        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        emailIntent.setType("text/plain");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, getString(R.string.app_name));
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text to share");
        emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri); //............Pass Image URI here.........
        emailIntent.setType("image/*");
        emailIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Share..."));
    }
```

Comment: tnx for your response.. its not working. It must be added to External storage.

Comment: Please check now, I tried in my device, its working fine now

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 boolean isWhatsappInstalled = whatsappInstalledOrNot("com.whatsapp");
                if (isWhatsappInstalled) {
                    Intent sendIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT,"http://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=" + getPackageName());
                    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse(MediaStore.Images.Media.insertImage(getContentResolver(), getBitMap(), "I am Happy", "Share happy !")));
                    sendIntent.setType("image/png");
                    sendIntent.setPackage("com.whatsapp");
                    sendIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
                    startActivity(sendIntent);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "WhatsApp not Installed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    Uri uri = Uri.parse("market://details?id=com.whatsapp");
                    Intent goToMarket = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
                    startActivity(goToMarket);

                }
```

where getBitMap() is function in which get the image bitmap which you want to share.

Answer (score 0):

Use Below Code for every app in you can share image, like whats app, hike or mail and many other

```
Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
shareIntent.setType("image/png");
Uri uri = Uri.parse("android.resource://" + getPackageName() + "/"+R.mipmap.ic_launcher);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uri);
shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Hello, This is test Sharing");
startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Send your image"));
```